# Dynamically Update Crosstab View from MySQL Trigger

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, triggers, crosstab

I'm attempting to de-normalize some data in a crosstab view which is dynamically generated on the MySQL server.  Due to a helpful answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3122424/dynamic-mysql-query-view-for-crosstab), I've successfully created a stored procedure which generates this crosstab view.

This is my procedure:

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE PROCEDURE `PartFlow`.`DimMatTab` ()
BEGIN
    SET @cols = (
    SELECT
    GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
        CONCAT(
            '\nSUM(IF(dimension_id = ',
            dimension_id,
            ', value, NULL)) AS ',
            name
        )
    ) as column_list
    FROM PartFlow.tDimMatMap
    JOIN PartFlow.tDimension
        on tDimension.id_dimension = tDimMatMap.dimension_id
    );

    SET @sql = CONCAT(
        'CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW `PartFlow`.`vDimMatTab` AS '
        'SELECT material_id, ',
        @cols,
        ' FROM tDimMatMap ',
        'GROUP BY material_id;');
    PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
    EXECUTE stmt;
END
```

Which produces a view containing this query:

```
select
`material_id`
,sum(if((`dimension_id` = 2),`value`,NULL)) AS `Width`
,sum(if((`dimension_id` = 3),`value`,NULL)) AS `Height`
,sum(if((`dimension_id` = 5),`value`,NULL)) AS `Thickness`
from `PartFlow`.`tDimMatMap`
group by `material_id`
```

I'd like the view to be updated on any changes to tDimMatMap, so that the view will always contain the right crosstab columns.  I've tried triggering the procedure on any insert, update, or delete on this source table.  Here is my trigger code:

```
create trigger update_view_iMat after insert on tDimMatMap
for each row call DimMatTab();$$

create trigger update_view_uMat after update on tDimMatMap
for each row call DimMatTab();$$

create trigger update_view_dMat after delete on tDimMatMap
for each row call DimMatTab();$$
```

In my mind, this is a perfect setup, but when I try to edit the tDimMatMap table, I get the error message, "Dynamic SQL is not allowed in stored function or trigger".  Is there any way to get around this?  Am I approaching the problem from the wrong angle?  I simply want to make sure that my crosstab view always contains a column for every unique "dimension_id" listed in the tDimMatMap table.

I am accessing this data from multiple client front-ends, so this centralized solution seems right. I'm sure that some would say that I should generate my SQL code outside the server, or run the procedure to grab my data without creating a view, but I cannot dynamically update this view within my clients, nor can I query by calling a procedure within my clients.  Most importantly, this view will be joined to other views and tables in certain applications, so creating the view is pretty important.